# Unclear step in derivation of Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, many-body

This question is concerned with the derivation of equation $(7)$ in this article

[N-fermion ground state of Calogero-Sutherland type models in two and higher dimensions](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0375-9601(98)00449-6)

a preprint(arxiv) version of the same article is available [here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9804212)

The author claims that by inserting (5) into (3) he obtains (7). However, I find this computation far from obvious. Can anybody add some details to this computation?

To address the comments:
I understand that the Slater determinant leads to the sum of eigenvalues of the $N$-lowest states when applied to the harmonic oscillator, I am struggeling with how it acts on the $1/r^{12}$ potential and how on the $(r_i-r_j) (\nabla_i-\nabla_j)$ term. I just don't know how to deal with the Slater determinant structure when tackling these two terms.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I don't want to be blunt but you really should work out this by your own hand or this will be useless.

Comment: @OON, it sounds like he doesn't know how to do it...

Comment: @BobakHashemi and until he tries he wouldn't really know. At least the question should be "I would do this and this but I don't understand this specific thing" or "I did the computation but my result is different and I don't know why" not the current one in the form "substitute A to B".

Comment: @OON yes, I don't know how this step is done. I understand there is a harmonic oscillator in there, but I don't know how to simplify the other terms when dealing with a Slater determinant. So how can I simplify the Slater determinant acting on the remaining terms?

Comment: That article is behind a paywall. You should include the relevant equations in the question, or at least link to the arxiv version: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9804212

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the author means by "$N \times N$ Slater determinant" in this context. What are the single particle states here?

Comment: It might be fruitful to contact the author directly and ask for details. I think most authors are eager to help readers understand their paper.